# Prove that a number, $x$ is strictly between $1$ and $\sqrt{a}$ iff $\frac{a}{x}$ is strictly between $\sqrt{a}$ and $a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that a number, $x$ is strictly between $1$ and $\sqrt{a}$ if and only if $\frac{a}{x}$ is strictly between $\sqrt{a}$ and $a$.

You may assume that $1 < \sqrt{a} < a$

What I have thus far:

**Theorem.** $1 < x < \sqrt{a} \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{a} < \frac{a}{x} < a$

*Proof.* We must prove: $1 < x < \sqrt{a} \Longrightarrow \sqrt{a} < \frac{a}{x} < a$ and 
$\sqrt{a} < \frac{a}{x} < a \Longrightarrow 1 < x < \sqrt{a}$

We first prove: $1 < x < \sqrt{a} \Longrightarrow \sqrt{a} < \frac{a}{x} < a$

$$1 < x < \sqrt{a}$$

$$\Rightarrow 1 \cdot \sqrt{a} < x \cdot \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{a}$$

$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{a} < x \sqrt{a} < a$$

We must now prove: $\sqrt{a} < \frac{a}{x} < a \Longrightarrow 1 < x < \sqrt{a}$

$$\sqrt{a} < \frac{a}{x} < a$$

$$\Rightarrow x \cdot \sqrt{a} < x \cdot \frac{a}{x} < x \cdot a$$

$$\Rightarrow x \sqrt{a} < a < xa$$

$$\Rightarrow x \sqrt{a} < a < xa$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{x \sqrt{a}}{a} < \frac{a}{a} < \frac{xa}{a}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{x}{\sqrt{a}} < 1 < x$$

---

I am having an issue with figuring out how to show that both sides of the biconditional are true. I would appreciate some help and/or guidance.

Comment: Both $a$ and $x \in R?$

Comment: For $x,y > 0$, we have that : if $x < y$, then $\dfrac 1 x > \dfrac 1 y$ (check with $2,4$).

Comment: Thus, for the first part : $1 < x < \sqrt a$ and divide by $a > 0$ : $\dfrac 1 a < \dfrac x a < \dfrac { \sqrt a } a = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt a}$.

Comment: By the above : $a > \dfrac a x > \sqrt a$.